# No traffic tc class at bridge interface

Tags: bridge, tc, network-interface

I make bridge interface like this

```
[root@]# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br67        8000.002655e38b20   no      eth6
                                        eth7
```

and I make tc class like this

```
tc qdisc add dev br67 root handle 1:0 htb default 2
tc class add dev br67 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev br67 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
```

But, when I monitoring using `watch /sbin/tc -s -d class show dev br67`
there is no traffic like this

```
class htb 1:1 root rate 8000Mbit ceil 8000Mbit burst 0b/8 mpu 0b overhead 0b cburst 0b/8 mpu 0b overhead 0b level 7
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
 lended: 0 borrowed: 0 giants: 0
 tokens: 15 ctokens: 15

class htb 1:2 parent 1:1 prio 0 quantum 200000 rate 8000Mbit ceil 8000Mbit burst 0b/8 mpu 0b overhead 0b cburst 0b/8 mpu 0b overh
ead 0b level 0
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
 lended: 0 borrowed: 0 giants: 0
 tokens: 15 ctokens: 15
```

when using `tcpdump -i br67` there is a traffic like this

```
10:25:35.048982 IP 122.189.906.11.64850 > 11.13.153.110.mxi: UDP, length 1470
10:25:35.064462 IP 122.189.906.11.64850 > 14.13.153.110.mxi: UDP, length 1470
```

when I make tc class using physical interface like `tc class add dev eth6  ..` or `tc class add dev eth7  ..`

I could watch traffic at tc class

Is it impossible to control traffic using tc command at bridge interface?

Comment: You need to add a filter to send packets to a particular class. Did you able to make it work ? I am blocked with similar bridge network and my tc rules don't work inspite of adding a filter.